# What happens if the ObjectContext.Refresh method cannot connect to your SQL server to perform a refresh if your SQL server is no longer reachable?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework and am wondering what happens if the ObjectContext.Refresh method cannot connect to your SQL server to perform a refresh if your SQL server is no longer reachable.

This MSDN article does not, as far as I can tell, show any related exceptions for this method: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

So what actually happens in this scenario? In my specific case I am trying to refresh an entity data model accessor table: `_entities.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, _entities.ProfilesTable);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would throw an `EntityException` that contains the provider-specific exception.